# Elastic Search and MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm currently using MongoMapper as an ORM and I would like to use Elastic Search. I tried integrating elasticsearch-rails to my project and called the import method, but I'm getting the following error.

Elasticsearch::Model::NotImplemented: Method not implemented for default adapter

Comment: Have you solved the question?

Comment: I switched to Mongoid